# React NextJS page navigation with tabs - display not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm attempting to navigate between pages using tabs:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs'
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const LinkTab = (props) => 
{
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleTabChange = (e) =>
  {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push(e.target.href)
  }

  return (
    <Tab
      component = 'a'
      onClick = {e => handleTabChange(e)}
      {...props} />
  )
}

const NavTabs = () => 
{
  const pages = ['/', '/two', '/three']
  const [value, setValue]  =  useState(0)

  const handleChange  =  (e, v)  => 
  {
    setValue(v)
  }

  return (
    <Box sx = {{width: '100%'}}>
      <Tabs value = {value} onChange = {(e, v) => handleChange(e, v)} centered>
        <LinkTab label = 'Page One' href = {pages[0]} />
        <LinkTab label = 'Page Two' href = {pages[1]} />
        <LinkTab label = 'Page Three' href = {pages[2]} />
      </Tabs>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default NavTabs
```

This works in terms of navigation - clicking a tab takes you to the expected page.

But the selected tab doesn't update correctly on the actual display.

Related error message (doesn't cause a crash but shows in console):

> next-dev.js?3515:32 MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
> The Tab with this `value` ("0") is not part of the document layout.
> Make sure the tab item is present in the document or that it's not `display: none`.

[image]

When the site first loads, `Page One` is the home page and is also correctly shown as selected. If I click on `Page Two` I navigate there right away, but I have to click on it again to actually have the tab display update to show that page as selected. And then if I click on `Page Three`, I'll again navigate there correctly, but the display will go back to showing `Page One` as selected.

I think this has something to do with when/where I call `e.preventDefault()` and the fact that state is being initiated with `0` for the first page. But I'm new to React, so I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong.

The code above is modified from the MUI example found [here](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs). Implementing the example code exactly as is correctly updates the display, but doesn't actually navigate, so I had to make some changes to use the router.

The `NavTabs` component is part of an `AppBar` component.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. It navigates and changes the tab well for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing missing in your code is the fact that you are always setting your value as 0 initially. Whereas it should be dependent on the page you are at

Modify your NavTabs component like this:

```
const router = useRouter();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(pages.indexOf(router.route));
```

`router` will give you the route and you can use it. The above example is basic and does not account for cases when pages does not include your route.